# ggmap is unable to plot specific region

Tags: r, google-maps, ggplot2, ggmap

I am trying to plot a specific region in the arctic with `ggmap`. The center of the region is somewhere around lat. 80 lon. 0, unfortunately only a grey background and the latitude and longitude axis are shown. I tried to plot different regions and my code seems to work on every location, except regions which are beyond lat. 73.6. Here is an example of my code:

```
library(ggmap)
library(mapproj)
location <- get_map(location = c(lon = 0, lat = 80), zoom = 4, maptype = "hybrid")
ggmap(location)
```

So does anyone know, why `ggmap` is unable to plot this location?

Comment: Hi! It may be related to this issue: https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues/6. They refer to `?mapproject`: "Points deemed unprojectable (such as north of 80 degrees latitude in the Mercator projection) are returned as NA.".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem (when trying to plot Antartica) and to get around it, I resorted to `ggplot`, but relying on a couple of functions from the `ggmap` package.
As @Henrik's link suggests, the map projection seems to be the problem.

#### The entire idea and code is courtesy of David Kahle

Here's what you can do to get it to work for your case:

```
location <- get_map(location = c(lon = 0, lat = 80), zoom = 4, maptype = "hybrid")

#Create a small data frame to pass to ggplot
fourCorners <- expand.grid(
  lon = as.numeric(attr(location, "bb")[, c("ll.lon", "ur.lon")]), 
  lat = as.numeric(attr(location, "bb")[, c("ll.lat", "ur.lat")])
  )
# The inset_raster function needs 4 data coordinates. Pull it out of your "location" that you got via get_map
xmin <- attr(location, "bb")$ll.lon
xmax <- attr(location, "bb")$ur.lon
ymin <- attr(location, "bb")$ll.lat
ymax <- attr(location, "bb")$ur.lat

# Now you are ready to plot it
mp <- ggplot(fourCorners, aes(x = lon, y = lat) ) + 
 inset_raster(location, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)            
mp
```

Which gives you your "hybrid" map, centered at (Longitude=0, lat=80)

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Perfect solution for my problem.